# compact and beautiful text coding

Tags: php, wordpress

How to make my code more compact and beautiful. I think that it is possible to shorten it more, but unfortunately I do not know at all how. I hope that you will help me, dear specialists.

```
<?php
$postidid = get_the_ID();
$args = array(
     'orderby' => 'rand',
     'showposts' => 10,
     'cat' => '-47,-56',
     'post__not_in' => array( $postidid),
     'meta_query' => array( array('key' => 'expost', 'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'))
);

$args1 = array(
     'orderby' => 'rand',
     'showposts' => 10,
     'cat' => '76',
     'post__not_in' => array( $postidid),
     'meta_query' => array( array('key' => 'expost', 'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'))
);

$args2 = array(
     'orderby' => 'rand',
     'showposts' => 10,
     'cat' => '34',
     'post__not_in' => array( $postidid),
     'meta_query' => array( array('key' => 'expost', 'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'))
);

$news = new WP_query(); 

if( in_category(76)) {
$news->query($args1);
} elseif (in_category(34)){
$news->query($args2);
} else {
$news->query($args);
}


 ?>
<ul class="list" style="text-align:center;"><?php while ($news->have_posts()) : $news->the_post(); ?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_post_image();?>" class="thumbnail" alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"></a><br><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="post-title" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

Sorry for My English

Comment: Your 3 different queries all appear to be the same except for the `cat` value, if you wanted to make it shorter you could define an array with the other values, and use `$news->query(array_merge($commonArgs, ['cat' => <category here>]))`

Comment: I think this question probably isn't quite the sort of thing SO is designed for though, as coding style is likely to be opinion based

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can try this way. It can help you.

```
<?php
$postidid = get_the_ID();
$args     = array(
    'orderby'        => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post__not_in'   => array( $postidid ),
    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'expost',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
        )
    ),
    'tax_query'      => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => array( - 47, - 56 )
        )
    )
);
$news     = new WP_Query();
if ( in_category( 76 ) ) {
    $args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => array( 76 )
        )
    );
    $news->query( $args );
} elseif ( in_category( 34 ) ) {
    $args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => array( 34 )
        )
    );
    $news->query( $args );
} else {
    $news->query( $args );
}
if ( $news->have_posts() ):?>

    <ul class="list" style="text-align:center;">
        <?php while ( $news->have_posts() ):
            $news->the_post(); ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_post_image(); ?>" class="thumbnail" alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"></a><br><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="post-title" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
<?php
endif;
```